# Can 10k+ users turn off the visibility of deleted posts?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools

The FAQ says that 10k+ users can view deleted posts.

Can they also choose to not see them at a given time?

Comment: You are pretty far from 10k, as far as what others choose to see or not to see - you have absolutely no control about in this context. I don't see the point in this question, at all.

Comment: If one cannot turn off the deleted posts, I might not *want* to get 10k.

Comment: If you see no point in having 10k+ reputation then just offer huge bounties on worthy questions and post as CW any answer you're giving.

Comment: You can see the deleted posts, but only if you go to them directly. Deleted questions will not show up in question lists, so you would only go there if another post linked to them. Deleted answers will be visible on the question page, but probably sorted below others if they got downvotes, and with a different background color. So for normal operation of the site you won't notice the difference.

Comment: @Phira: So...what is it like being able to see deleted posts? Do you agree with your former self? I am intrigued...

Comment: Agree with what? That I still would like very much to be able to turn off the deleted posts? Of course. Do you think reputation above 10k magically makes me LOVE advice of the kind "Just do not read it / give away your reputation if you do not like a particular feature / you wont notice the difference."? I cannot even imagine what would make me OPPOSE the possibility of turning off the deleted posts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We did change it a while ago so deleted answers always sort to the bottom of a question.

But in general we feel it is healthy for deleted answers (and deleted questions in certain circumstances) to get visibility in case they were deleted incorrectly or inappropriately or for the wrong reasons.

Comment: It's sounds like a good thing that they're alway at the bottom - nice!

Answer (score 11):

Not that I know of. There might be a clever javascript hack, but other than that... and why would you want to, anyway?

Comment: Because the deleted posts might be deleted for a reason?

Comment: You can always not read them...?

Comment: You can always not look at that car crash, too, but the temptation is too great....

Comment: @Gerry... most deleted posts are not that interesting!

Answer (score 8):

I just asked this question at meta.SO [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176920/).  I managed to get the proposed [Deleted Answer Manager](https://stackapps.com/questions/3408/stack-overflow-deleted-answer-manager) to work in Google Chrome on maths.SE by editing the script [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/133048).

Specifically, I changed the line

```
// @match        http://stackoverflow.com/*
```

to

```
// @match        http://math.stackexchange.com/*
```

Then installed the script via [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).  Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: Screenshot]

Clicking where it says "1 Deleted Answer" reveals the deleted answers.